# How to trigger radio button when text or another widget is tapped?

Tags: flutter, dart

I create Row with 2 widgets like this

```
Row(
   children: [
      new Radio(
        value: 0,
        groupValue: rv0,
        onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange1,
      ),

      GestureDetector(
         onTap: (){ //trigger radio button },
         child: Text('Tap Me')
      )
   ],
)
```

So, when I tap on the text, the radio will be triggered, for example in javascript with jquery

```
$('#radio').click()
```

How to do it in dart flutter? thanks

Answer (score 9):

```
    Row(
   children: [
      new Radio(
        value: 0,
        groupValue: rv0,
        onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange1,
      ),

      GestureDetector(
         onTap: (){ 
        //trigger radio button
//you can pass any value which is the value of respective radio button
_handleRadioValueChange1(0)
 },
         child: Text('Tap Me')
      )
   ],
)
```

or you can go for the RadioListTile widget.

Answer (score 6):

if you want to select radio button value on click of your `textview` Then you need change `groupValue`  of your radio button on click of your textview

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _State createState() => _State();
}

class _State extends State<MyApp> {
  int _radioValue1 = 0;

  void _handleRadioValueChange1(int value) {
    setState(() {
      _radioValue1 = value;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('RadioListTile Demo'),
      ),
      //hit Ctrl+space in intellij to know what are the options you can use in flutter widgets
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(32.0),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Radio(
                value: 0,
                groupValue: _radioValue1,
                onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange1,
              ),
              Radio(
                value: 1,
                groupValue: _radioValue1,
                onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange1,
              ),
              Radio(
                value: 2,
                groupValue: _radioValue1,
                onChanged: _handleRadioValueChange1,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _radioValue1 = 0;
                  });
                },
                child: Text("Select First Radio Button"),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _radioValue1 = 1;
                  });
                },
                child: Text("Select Second Radio Button"),
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                onTap: () {
                  setState(() {
                    _radioValue1 = 2;
                  });
                },
                child: Text("Select Third Radio Button"),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```